# Keeping ASP .NET from putting type="" on scripts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an ASP .NET Web Forms application that has several scripts and styles that are automatically showing as `<script type="text/javascript">`. These are either in my scriptmanager or other ASP .NET generated scripts. Is there any way to keep these scripts from displaying the type and just rendering as `<script>` instead? The same thing happens on the styles generated by ASP .NET. Anyway to have it not do that?

The reason I want to do such is because I'm getting validation warnings in the W3 HTML5 validator.

Comment: Why? It is required for [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT) and lower. No longer required for HTML 5.

Comment: I was trying to deal with validation warnings in an HTML 5 page.